# How to write outputs with header by using writecsv/writedlm in JULIA

Tags: database, julia, export-to-csv

The following code works in Julia, which writes the values of `A`, `B`, with a header.

I am questioning if there is a more elegant way to introduce the header as an option in `writecsv` or `writedlm`

```
Header = ["a" "b"]
A= [1,2,3]
B=[3,4,5]
Data = [Header ; A[:]  B[:]]
Path =  "//OUTPUT//Table//Hydraulic_Inv.csv"
println(Path)
writecsv(Path ,Data )
```

the output

```
 a,b
 1,3
 2,4
 3,5
```

Comment: Sorry for the mass of edits. I ended up significantly altering my answer (and slightly altering your question) so it is compatible with future versions of Julia.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, `writecsv` is deprecated in v0.7, so it is probably best not to start using it now as it will be completely gone in v1.0.

Why are they getting rid of `writecsv`? Because for v1.0, julia `Base` is being stripped back to absolute essentials. If you need to work with csv files in v1.0, the recommended approach is to use the [CSV](http://juliadata.github.io/CSV.jl/stable/) package. For example (using Julia v1.1.1):

```
using CSV, DataFrames
x = [1 2 ; 3 4]
header = ["a", "b"]
CSV.write(somefilepath, DataFrame(x), header=header)
```

Note that in Julia v1.0 it was:

```
CSV.write(somefilepath, DataFrame(x), colnames=header)
```

It would be nice if you didn't have to wrap `x` in a call to `DataFrame`. I'm assuming at some point a wrapper will be put in place so that doesn't have to happen. In the meantime, it is a minor inconvenience.

If you absolutely insist on only using functions in `Base`, then going forward you will need to use `writedlm`. This function does not have an option for adding a header, so you  basically need to do what you are currently doing, ie:

```
x = [1 2 ; 3 4]
header = ["a" "b"]
writedlm(somefilepath, ',', [header ; x])
```

Note the second argument ensures the delimiter in the written file is a comma.

Also note that this approach will almost certainly be slower (eventually) than using `CSV`. This is because `[header ; x]` constructs an interim temporary array of type `Any`, which (as I understand things) means the subsequent write operation will be fairly inefficient. In contrast, the `CSV` package tools are (will be) optimized precisely to avoid these sorts of problems, and ideally get read/write times that are compatible with reading and writing dataframes in R (ie, very fast).

Comment: @Joseph.Pollacco Oops yes forgot to change the vector to a row vector when copy-pasting. Good catch.

Comment: In v1.1.1 you have to use `CSV.write(somefilepath, DataFrame(x), header=header)`

Comment: @HenriqueAndrade Thanks for the heads up. I've edited the answer.

Comment: I'm using Julia 1.9v, the way of `writedlm` does not work for me. `CSV.write(somefilepath, DataFrame(x), header=header)` works but `DataFrame(x)` needs to be `DataFrame(x,:auto)`. It automatically name a series of columns.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for providing so insightful answer and for explaining the future of JULIA. Just a correction of     writedlm to work:

```
x = [1 2 ; 3 4]
header = ["a", "b"]
writedlm(somefilepath [header ; x], ",",)
```

Comment: Just FYI, you should delete this answer as it just duplicates the (useful) correction you provided to my answer. Raising it in the comments to my answer (which you also did) is the correct way on StackOverflow to deal with this kind of situation.