# how dose "writecsv() " work in JuliaPro 1.5.0?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

Would you please help me?
How is it possible to export the results in Excel in JuliaPro 1.5.0?
I used to use writecsv() such as writecsv("C:\admin\users\Desktop\maincoreectedmodel10.csv",sortlist(List)) in Juliapro 0.6.4

but it makes the error in JuliaPro 1.5.0

```
UndefVarError: writecsv not defined
in include_string at base\loading.jl:1088
in top-level scope at NLtri.juliarc.jl:101
```

would you please say where is the problem?
Thanks :) .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`writecsv` has been removed from Julia a long time ago, your question is basically answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49684406/2499892

(To summarize you should install the `CSV` package and do `using CSV; CSV.write("myfile.csv", my_data)`)